# Mysql Trigger not working. Add current date to where clause

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to triggers using with MySQL.

I wrote a trigger for copy row to another table by considering date.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `new` AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW
insert into employee_log (first_name, last_name)
select first_name, last_name from employee
where start_date = '2013-07-11'
```

My employee table `start_date` format is `date`. How to get current date as `start_date =  '2013-07-12'` ?

I tried `start_date = now()` in trigger but nothing copied.

My `employee` table structure provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When insert a record to this table trigger check `start_date` is **today/current date** then copy row in to `employee_log` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_log` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lasinserted` time DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: how can i found a solution

Comment: I don't think you should  SELECT from mutating table in it's trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `employee_new` AFTER INSERT 
ON `employee` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (new.start_date >= currdate ()) 
  THEN 
  INSERT INTO employee_log (first_name, last_name) 
  VALUES
    (new.first_name, new.last_name) ;
  END IF ;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

format now() as current date using date_format function

```
CREATE TRIGGER `new` AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW
insert into employee_log (first_name, last_name)
select first_name, last_name from employee
where start_date = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') /*DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') represents current date as format %Y-%m-%d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your trigger a one-statement one (meaning not changing delimiter and using `BEGIN...END` block) and still do the job you can do following

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_employee_after_insert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO employee_log (id, first_name, last_name, end_date, city, description, Lasinserted)
  SELECT NEW.id, 
         NEW.first_name, 
         NEW.last_name, 
         NEW.end_date, 
         NEW.city, 
         NEW.description, 
         NOW()
    FROM dual
   WHERE NEW.start_date = CURDATE();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69670/1)** demo

Comment: Don't you think *explicit select* would lead to *cumulative* duplicates rows insertion?

Comment: @Ravinder Fair enough. It actually meant to be a select from `dual`. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if newly added `start_date` is `curdate()`. If `'true'` then `'insert'` into log table.

**Example**:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `new` AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  CASE WHEN NEW.start_date = CURRENT_DATE THEN
    INSERT
      INTO employee_log( first_name, last_name )
    VALUES ( NEW.first_name, NEW.last_name );
  END CASE;
END;
//

delimiter ;
```

But from understanding the table structure and its name, I am assuming that you want to log the latest added record of the employee table. To do that you have to include all the columns from the record.

**Example**:

```
  CASE WHEN NEW.start_date = CURRENT_DATE THEN
    INSERT
      INTO employee_log( id, first_name, last_name, 
                         start_date, end_date,
                         city, description, Lasinserted )
    VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.first_name, NEW.last_name, 
             NEW.start_date, NEW.end_date,
             NEW.city, NEW.description, NEW.lasinserted );
  END CASE;
```